# Encrypt directory on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, security, encryption, authentication

I need to create an encrypted directory (to be then filled with files and subdirectories) in a Linux `ext4` filesystem, accessible to just one user. It should be:

- visible (just the root) from the non-encrypted filesystem;
- accessible with a *separate password*, not the one used in the user's login;
- once unlocked, accessible and usable like a normal directory.

According to other questions, `gpg` and `openssl` should be excluded because they would require `tar`. The same for EncFS, which is not always secure.

1) Which tool can be used here?

2) If `ecryptfs` is a solution, it seems to unlock the directory through the user's password. Is there a way to create a dedicated password, other than the user's one?

Comment: re `ecryptfs`, look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/574110/how-to-use-ecryptfs-with-a-random-directory, I think what you want is possible.

Comment: thanks, I will read and maybe even try. But it is a workaround. I were looking for something more direct, if it exists.

Comment: A solution I use is [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) (a decent TrueCrypt replacement).

Comment: Why are you excluding encfs? With your requirements, that's the right tool.

Comment: @seejayemm I will give a look!

Comment: @Gilles Because it has some known vulnerabilities that make it unreliable in certain situations.